# sqlalchemy one to many join in flask app to get max date

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**My Data**
rowid, job (not unique), status, date.

**Query need**
Return results unique by job
max date of status ==1 and
max date of status== 0
on the same returned row.

why doesn't this work (and is this the best approach?)?:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

j=aliased(models.Jobs)

y=db.session.query(j.job,j.status,\
  func.max(j.start).\
  label("start")).\
  filter(j.status ==0).\
  group_by(j.job)   

x=db.session.query(models.Jobs.job,\
  models.Jobs.status,\
  func.max(models.Jobs.start).\
  label("start")).\
  filter(models.Jobs.status ==1).\
  group_by(models.Jobs.job)

  nj=x.join(y,x[0]==y[0])#i tried x.job, but it claimed it didn't have a job
```

s trace gives me

```
>>> nj=x.join(y,x[0]==y[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "K:\Meinzer\Production\ProjectManagement\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\orm\query.py", line 1638, in join
    from_joinpoint=from_joinpoint)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "K:\Meinzer\Production\ProjectManagement\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\orm\query.py", line 50, in generate
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
  File "K:\Meinzer\Production\ProjectManagement\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\orm\query.py", line 1767, in _join
    outerjoin, create_aliases, prop)
  File "K:\Meinzer\Production\ProjectManagement\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\orm\query.py", line 1807, in _join_left_to_right
    onclause, outerjoin)
  File "K:\Meinzer\Production\ProjectManagement\flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalche
my\orm\query.py", line 1952, in _join_to_left
    "Tried joining to %s, but got: %s" % (right, ae))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.
Tried joining to SELECT jobs_1.job AS job, jobs_1.status AS jobs_1_status, max(j
obs_1.start) AS start
FROM jobs AS jobs_1
WHERE jobs_1.status = :status_1 GROUP BY jobs_1.job, but got: Can't find any for
eign key relationships between 'jobs' and '_FromGrouping object'. Perhaps you me
ant to convert the right side to a subquery using alias()?
>>>
```

Here is my model (should i be starting with Syntax?)

```
class Syntax(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True,)
    jobs = db.relationship('Jobs',lazy='dynamic', backref='jobhistory')
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<filename %r>' % (self.filename)

class Jobs(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    job = db.Column(db.String(150),db.ForeignKey('syntax.filename'))
    start = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    stop = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer())  
    when = db.Column(db.String(150))  
    cat= db.Column(db.String(150))  
    message  = db.Column(db.String(150))  
    errorvar = db.Column(db.String(150))   
    errormsgvar = db.Column(db.String(150))  
    # syntaxhistory_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('syntax.filename')) 
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Job %r>' % (self.job)
```

Comment: Show full traceback, there is line numer which has problem. Show this line and neighborhood.

Comment: Maybe you need `jobs` in place of `job` in some place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query below will return the data you are looking for as *list* of tuples `(Syntax, max_start0, max_start1)`:

```
q = (db.session.query(Syntax,
        func.max(case([(Jobs.status == 0, Jobs.start)])).label("max_start0"),
        func.max(case([(Jobs.status == 1, Jobs.start)])).label("max_start1"),
        )
    .outerjoin(Jobs)
    .group_by(Syntax)
    )
```

*If you want only `filename` (and not the whole `Syntax` instances), just replace `Syntax` with `Syntax.filename` in both `query(...)` and `group_by(...)`.*

Comment: amazing, thank you! I'll be helping you with your queries soon!